# Google maps API function getlatlong

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, google-maps-api-3, geocode

I have this code and problem is that $address_array extract just last position in the array.

How should I fix it?

HMTL

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

JQUERY

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
function getlatlong($address){
        $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . urlencode($address) . '&sensor=true';
        $json = @file_get_contents($url);
        $data = json_decode($json);
        if ($data->status == "OK")
             return $data;
        else
             return false;
}
$address_array = array('Germany', 'Poland', 'Italy');
foreach ($address_array as $address) {
     $data = getlatlong($address);
     $location = $data->results[0]->geometry->location;
}
?>
```

JS creat map

```
<script>
    function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 3,
          center: {lat: -28.024, lng: 140.887}
        });
    }
</script>
<script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: Data/location are overwritten in every loop iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Fixed

> This code wrote one guy and it works great.

The code returns latlng positions.

```
$address_array = array("Germany", "Poland", "Italy","Italy","Italy");
    $encoded_adress_array = [];

    foreach ($address_array as $address) {
        array_push($encoded_adress_array, getlatlong($address)->results[0]->geometry->location);
    }
```